# Can focal point of a lens be a line instead of a point

Tags: optics, lenses

Is there any lens OR can we have a lens that will focus light in form of a line instead of a point. Some sort of a rectangular convex lens.

Comment: Think of a "cylindrical" lens: thickness varies in 1 direction only.

Comment: Astigmatism in the eye occurs when the focus is not a point but a line segment.

Comment: It will help if you clarify whether you'd like this line in the direction of propagation or orthogonal to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make a line focus.

You can try to use two perpendicular cylindrical lenses of different focal lengths.

Or you can try to use one spherical and one cylindrical lens.

Or you can put the spherical lens at an angle the astigmatism of the lens will generate the line focus.

If you use only one cylindrical lens then you can not control the length of the line.

Another lens is axicon lens, that do not generate line focus in perpendicular direction but in the direction of propagation.